# Поздравляем, вы больше не в бете!

Tags: обсуждение, выход-из-беты

## Наши поздравления, «Русский язык»! Вы больше не в бете!

**Этот сайт вошёл в бета-стадию до июля 2012 года, поэтому сейчас мы завершаем её — теперь по нашим меркам «Русский язык» является полноценным сайтом**. Мы удалили надпись «Бета» из названия, потому что уверены, что вы уже не «Бета» — даже в отсутствие десяти вопросов в день.

[image: Banner that reads "Congratulations" in gold cursive text]

### История вопроса

Я считаю, что нам нужно [избавиться от пометки «Бета» для сайтов с длинной историей и отказаться от процесса аттестации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/lets-break-up-with-graduation-and-remove-a-bunch-of-beta-labels) — или как минимум значительно его переработать — и я не одинока в своём убеждении. Мы хорошо понимаем абсурдность того, что сайты с многолетней биографией до сих пор имеют ярлык «Бета» в названии без всякой на то причины.

[Аттестация без создания собственного дизайна](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) была важным шагом, который разделил аттестацию и создание полноценного дизайна для сайтов... но он всё равно оставил сайты с менее чем десятью вопросами за день в состоянии неопределённости.

Примерно в то же время [мы осознали, что «небольшие сайты» могут никогда не достичь этого показателя](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), хотя в то же время будут оставаться успешными и не будут под угрозой, пока способны поддерживать процесс модерирования — удалять спам, следить за актуальностью вопросов и т. п. Этот шаг дал вам уверенность в том, что сайт гарантированно не будет закрыт.

Почти через четыре года с этого заявления благодаря сообщениям на [многих](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/will-video-se-be-stuck-in-beta-forever) из ваших [Мета-сайтов](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/how-can-we-push-ourselves-out-of-beta) и [даже на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322781/writing-se-clamours-for-graduation) [стало ясно](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/do-we-have-any-chance-of-graduating-any-time-soon), что неспособность избавиться от надписи «Бета» в названии — большая проблема для сообществ; настало время обратиться к ней.

### Что всё это значит?

Следующие изменения вскоре произойдут с этим сайтом:

- исчезнет надпись «Бета» из названия,
- с главной страницы исчезнет баннеры «Статистика сайта» и «Поделиться сайтом»,
- сохранятся пороги для получения привилегий,
- полноценные выборы будут отложены, но останутся запланированными на более позднее время.

Это — начальная точка для процесса, который уже обсуждается нами и будет вынесен на публичное рассмотрение, как только мы подготовим план действий. Я надеюсь, что это положит конец такой неудобной вещи, как аттестация (в смысле списку целей, которые необходимо достичь, чтобы запустить процесс аттесатции).

Уверена, у вас много вопросов — не стесняйтесь их задавать (в ответах), и я отвечу что смогу. Будет значительно проще, если вы сфокусируетесь на какой-то одной теме вместо того, чтобы задавать несколько вопросов за раз.

MSE (на английском): [Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta)

Большое спасибо за ваше терпение и за то, что остаётесь с нами!

Answer (score 0):

> не стесняйтесь их задавать (в ответах)

У меня простой вопрос:

Кроме исчезновения слова "Бета" из названия, хоть какие-то изменения уже произошли? Скоро произойдут? Планируются?

Comment: На протяжении всего этого времени никакой конкретной информации, касающейся вашего вопроса, не было. Сейчас ситуация изменилась, и вскоре на Мете появится (по крайней мере, мы ожидаем) специальный анонс. Спасибо за интерес к сайту!

Comment: @Aer Спасибо, я уж и забыл про свой вопрос :) Будем ждать новостей.