# Хотели бы вы стать модератором?

Tags: обсуждение, выход-из-беты

Друзья, наш сайт больше не в [бета-стадии](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/178412), а это значит, что пришло время полноценных выборов в модераторы сообщества.

Если вы заинтересованы в этом, **пожалуйста, оставьте ответ под этим сообщением**.
**NB:** это не официальный старт выборов, а всего лишь «проверка пульса» — мы хотели бы выяснить примерное число кандидатур.

Вот с чем связан модераторский статус:

- необходимо досконально изучить правила сайта;
- после этого — следить за их соблюдением, предотвращать их нарушение;
- с последним помогают тревоги, оставляемые другими участниками;
- помимо вышеперечисленного нужно давать ответы на вопросы других участников на Мета-сайте;

*необязательная, но крайне важная и полезная часть:*

- нужно принимать активное участие во внутренних и внешних обсуждениях, связанных с развитием сайта;
- предлагать и комментировать идеи акций, способствующих развитию сайта.

Ждём ваших откликов!

(Да, на данном этапе достаточно лишь написать: «Я хотел бы!»)

Answer (score 2):

Ну коли так, восстанавливаю свою заявку, поданную год назад. )))

Уточняю: как и тогда, я совсем не рвусь во власть, но если реально нужно помочь, то располагаю и временем, и некоторыми навыками.

> NB: это не официальный старт выборов, а всего лишь «проверка пульса» —
>   мы хотели бы выяснить примерное число кандидатур.

Да шут бы с ним, что неофициальная, если все дело на этом не закончится.

Comment: Спасибо! Мы тоже надеемся, что на объявлении процесс не завершится :)